# how to push some of the object keys only into another array in react js

Tags: javascript

i am fetching some Items from back end, now i want to create separate duplicate array **ItemsModels** and want to post that items into back end...can any help on this ...

getting data from backend

```
  const Items = [
      { uid: "01", item: "Car", carModel: "i 20", model: 2010 },
      { uid: "02", item: "Car", carModel: "i 10", model: 2009 },
      { uid: "03", item: "Car", carModel: "Swift", model: 2011 },
      { uid: "04", item: "Car", carModel: "Polo", model: 2015 }
    ];
```

duplicate array i want like this....

```
 const ItemsModels = [
      { uid: "01", carModel: "Hundai i 20" },
      { uid: "02", carModel: "Hundai i 10" },
      { uid: "03", carModel: "Swift" },
      { uid: "04", carModel: "Polo" }
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do a simple map

```
const ItemsModels = Items.map(item => {
      const { uid, carModel } = item;
      return { uid, carModel };
});
```